# Graph and calculate any point mouse hovers with JS

Tags: javascript, html, graph, hover

Let's hope I can explain this well.

I'm looking to make a graph where the user can hover over ANY location on the graph and run a calculation on that particular (x,y) value as a hover popup.

Here's an example of what I'm kind of looking for (different data). My problem is I don't know exactly what the type of graph is being use to do my own research on it:

http://learnforeverlearn.com/adsense/

Answer (score 0):

This likely depends on the library being used.  In the case of that web site, it's using d3.js.

Here's a fairly complete example for getting the x,y coordinates using d3, at which point you can do whatever you want: http://www.d3noob.org/2014/07/my-favourite-tooltip-method-for-line.html.

Comment: Thanks. I'll experiment a bit with that. I don't exactly want a line graph so I'll have to find the x,y for every mouse position. This example matches it to the line it looks like.

Comment: I was able to use that example. I had to modify it a bit to keep track of mouse position but this is what I came up with: http://dayobject.me/apps/pellet_stove_graph/